# My JFrame code is not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am new to Java just messing around with building `JFrame` based apps. I removed all errors and extra imports but nothing shows up when I run it. It says was never launched cannot be launched.

```
package pack1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WindowDemo extends JFrame { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WindowDemo() { 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("hello!");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(300,200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program will start from the main(String[] args) method. Create an instance of WindowDemo there.

Comment: Change `WindowDemo extends JFrame` to just `WindowDemo`.  There is no need to extend frame here.

Comment: You have only defined a class. Create an entry point, which is the class having main() method, and instantiate this class in there.

Comment: *"It says was never launched cannot be launched."*  Is 'it' your IDE or your cat?  Please be specific.  Also always copy/paste error and exception output!  But as mentioned by @ZakiMak this app needs a `public static void main(String[])` method in order to run, but you should have worked that out from the [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) of the tutorial (which comes before even the 'nuts and bolts' section of the tutorial).  Go back and review the basics, please.

Comment: Never seen the Object-Oriented Programming Concepts Lesson but will check it out. I'm super new. So any thing helps. I'm using eclipse luna by the way.

Comment: @Zemaff: it is considered part of the netiquette that you work yourself through at least some basic tutorials about a programming language. This helps to prevent frustration for all of us – and you get a better understanding on what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This should work better:

```
package pack1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class WindowDemo{ 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public WindowDemo() { 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("hello!");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){ 
        new WindowDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: 1) Swing GUIs should be started on the EDT. 2) Best to `pack()` prior to `setVisible(true)` 3) I prefer `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`..

Comment: This worked thank you. I knew public static void main was important but I had it under frame.setVisible(true); and deleted it when it did not work. Thanks Again.